# Is it a good idea to remove Firefox, when it also removes "gnome-core"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-server

I thought I should remove Firefox since I don't use it, but if I run `apt-get purge firefox` it says that it will remove `gnome-core` which seems like it could be needed by other apps on my VNC server.

Here is the terminal output:

[image: Shell]

Will this definitely only remove packages that are used by Firefox, or do I risk breaking other apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess to that is that since you are removing Firefox, it also wants to remove the rendering engine that it uses, Gecko, which is probably used as a dependency for some of those programs.  You could purge Firefox and keep everything else by ignoring dependencies, but it's not generally advisable.

On the up-side of that, if you choose to do that, it shouldn't render your system non-usable, but it may require you to drop to a command line to reinstall Firefox if the GUI does not load up completely.